# Jquery Masonry loading over each other after

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-masonry, masonry

Masonry loads all images over each another. After a page resize it works
Any solution please ?!

Comment: When you ask a question on stackoverflow, you need to provide your relevant code and ideally an example with jsfiddle or a link. A one sentence description and then asking for a solution is inadequate. Please edit your question and add more information

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap:

```
window.onload = function() { ... your code }
```

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

 
  var $grid = $('.grid').imagesLoaded( function() {
      $('.grid').masonry({
      // options
      itemSelector: '.grid__item',
     });
  });
  
  

  $('#menu-toggle').on('click', function () {
  $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
  $(this).toggleClass('toggled');
   });
   
   });

Comment: it's work?

window.onload = function() { var $grid = $('.grid').imagesLoaded( function() { $('.grid').masonry({ // options itemSelector: '.grid__item', }); }); $('#menu-toggle').on('click', function () { $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled'); $(this).toggleClass('toggled'); }) }